# EditText allow only alphabets, digits of all languages

Tags: android, android-edittext, multilingual, android-textwatcher, input-filter

I have an EditText in which i want to allow only alphabets and numbers of any language. I tried with different `android:inputType` and `android:digits` in XML.

I tried with set TextWatcher to edittext in which onTextChanged() is like

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        switch (et.getId()) {
        case R.id.edtMultiLang: {
            et.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);
            et.setText(s.toString().replaceAll("[^[:alpha:]0-9 ]", ""));
            // et.setText(s.toString().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", ""));
            et.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
            break;
        }
        }
    }
```

This is working fine. But whenever i tried to clear text, cursor is moving to start for every letter. Means when i clear a single letter, cursor moving to start.

If i use like `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "`, it allows me to type only alphabets and numbers of english. It is not allowing me to enter any other language text As i given only English related alphabets here. But my requirement is to allow copy/paste of other language's alphabets and letters also.
I hope we can do this by using Patterns, TextWatcher and InputFilter. But i didn't find better way.

Please let me know if there any way to do this.

Comment: I found solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953259/edittext-cursor-coming-to-start-for-every-letter-when-clear-text , but when i paste text, cursor moving to end

Answer (score 2):

The option you mention to resolve the problem is easy and fast, if you use a filter your code will be like this:

```
public static InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        String blockCharacterSet = "~#^|$%*!@/()-'\":;,?{}=!$^';,?×÷<>{}€£¥₩%~`¤♡♥_|《》¡¿°•○●□■◇◆♧♣▲▼▶◀↑↓←→☆★▪:-);-):-D:-(:'(:O 1234567890";
        if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Comment: thanks for reply josedlujan. In this we need to listout all special characters. we need to consider smilies also.

Comment: Also while copy, pasting text in edittext, it is not restricting these blocked symbols.

Comment: source can contain few symbols if you type it fast. The above code is not working for that case. You should split source per chars before doing replacements.