# EditText - Cursor coming to start for every letter when clear text

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I set `TextWatcher` to `EditText` like below. But when I try to clear text, cursor is coming to start after clearing every letter.

```
  class MyInputWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);
        et.setText(s.toString().replaceAll("[^[:alpha:]]", ""));
        et.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: use your code inside `afterTextChanged`

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this (UPDATED):

```
class MyInputWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String temp = s.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
        if (s.toString().length() != temp.length()) {
            et.setText(temp);
            et.setSelection(temp.length());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
}
```

Comment: this will give stack overflow exception

Comment: This is working fine but whenever paste text, cursor automatically moving to last position. In normal edit text it will not move like this.

Comment: i think then that will need a lot of customization.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Subhash Kumar, you can use method:

```
et.setSelection(position)
```

for displaying cursor in need position

Answer (score 0):

Every time you clear a character it calls `onTextChanged()` method, as your implementation it get the edittext text and back set to it, so the cursor comes to the starting of the text. Clear `et.setText(s.toString().replaceAll("[^[:alpha:]]", ""));` and it will be fixed. Or use this `et.setSelection(et.getText().toString().length+1);`

Comment: This will move the cursor to end of the text. If i want to clear from middle this will not work

Comment: Then clear this `et.setText(s.toString().replaceAll("[^[:alpha:]]", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

Set position to your cursor on afterTextChanged() method like this.

```
class MyInputWatcher implements TextWatcher {

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
    et.removeTextChangedListener(watcher2);
    et.setText(s.toString().replaceAll("[^[:alpha:]]", ""));
    et.addTextChangedListener(watcher2);
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    et.setSelection(et.getText().toString().length())
}
```

}

Comment: This will move the cursor to end of the text. If i want to clear from middle this will not work